# Compare and get missing values from two columns of two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables named StationUtilization and Process. Both tables have columns TestStart and TestDateTime respectively and should have similar records.

However, there are some missing records in TestStart column of StationUtilization table that needs to be added. How can I compare these two columns to get the missing values?

Example:

StationUtilization Table

| ID | TestStart | ..... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 22:42:23.000 |  |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 22:42:23.000 |  |
| 3 | 2021-01-05 22:42:23.000 |  |

Process Table:

| ID | TestDateTime | ..... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 22:42:23.000 |  |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 22:42:23.000 |  |
| 3 | 2021-01-03 22:42:23.000 |  |
| 4 | 2021-01-04 22:42:23.000 |  |
| 5 | 2021-01-05 22:42:23.000 |  |

Expected output after comparison:

| ID | TestDateTime | ..... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2021-01-03 22:42:23.000 |  |
| 4 | 2021-01-04 22:42:23.000 |  |

Comment: would you be so kind to provide some test data and desired output

Comment: A left or right outer join might be what you are after, selecting those entries with a NULL value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM StationUtilization
LEFT JOIN  Process
ON Process.TestDateTime = StationUtilization.TestStart
WHERE PROCESS.ID is null
```

Answer (score 1):

`NOT EXISTS` is one approach:

```
select p.*
from Process p
where not exists (select 1
                  from StationUtilization su
                  where p.TestDateTime = su.TestStart
                 );
```